# Meaning of "Lord it over"

Tags: greek, 2-corinthians

In 2 Corinthins 1:24 Paul claims he does not "lord it over" the Corinthians (according to the ESV translation).

What is that supposed to mean? Is there really not a better way to translate it?

Some other translations have something to the effect of "have dominion over."

Clearly this can't be just a blanket denigration of authority so what specifically does this Greek word mean? What does it look like? How can someone tell when someone is doing this? Or is it really just a generic abuse of power and the reader has to just figure out for himself what that looks like?

Answer (score 3):

The Greek text of 2 Cor. 1:24 states,

> <sup>ΚΔʹ</sup> οὐχ ὅτι κυριεύομεν ὑμῶν τῆς πίστεως ἀλλὰ συνεργοί ἐσμεν τῆς χαρᾶς ὑμῶν τῇ γὰρ πίστει ἑστήκατε <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

### On the Greek Word κυριεύομεν

The word κυριεύομεν is a verb conjugated in the 1st person, plural number, present tense, active voice, and indicative mood, from the lemma κυριεύω. The verb κυριεύω is a [denominative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denominal_verb) derived from the noun κύριος, meaning “master” (a.k.a. “lord”) or “owner.”<sup>1</sup> The ending -εύω forms a verb that means “to be a [noun].”<sup>2</sup> Thus, in the case of κυριεύω, the verb means “to be a master (of/over),”<sup>3</sup> just as the denominative verb δουλεύω means “to be a slave,”<sup>4</sup> derived from the noun δοῦλος, meaning “a slave,”<sup>5</sup> and βασιλεύω means “to be a king,”<sup>6</sup> derived from the noun βασιλεύς, meaning “a king.”<sup>7</sup>

The verb κυριεύω takes an object in the genitive case indicating of/over whom/what the subject is master. Therefore, the phrase «οὐχ ὅτι κυριεύομεν ὑμῶν τῆς πίστεως» *could* be translated into English as “not that we are masters of you of the faith...” Some translations (e.g., KJV) translate «ὑμῶν τῆς πίστεως» as “over your faith,” as though the pronoun «ὑμῶν» modifies «τῆς πίστεως». (The minor point concerns the fact that ὑμῶν precedes τῆς πίστεως.)

### The Impetus for the Apostle Paul’s Statement

What prompted the apostle Paul to make such a statement? Meyer<sup>8</sup> points to the word φειδόμενος, a conjugation of the lemma φείδομαι which LSJ defines as “to spare persons or things in using them.”<sup>9</sup> In other words, by using that particular word, it may have seemed to the Corinthians that the apostle Paul was implying he was their master—he could dictate how and when people were to be used. Pre-empting their objection, the apostle and his companions (i.e., “we”) wanted to emphasize that they were the Corinthians’ fellow-workers (συνεργοί), i.e. fellow-slaves (σύνδουλοι).<sup>10</sup>

Alford further provided the following insightful commentary,<sup>11</sup>

> But why ὑμῶν τῆς πίστεως? He had power over them, but it was in matters of discipline, not of faith: over matters of faith not even an Apostle has power (‘fides enim prorsus ab hominum jugo soluta liberrimaque esse debet.’ Calv.),<sup>12</sup> seeing it is in each man’s faith that he stands before God. And he puts this strongly, that in matters of faith he is only a fellow-helper of their joy (the χαρὰ ἐν τῷ πιστεύειν, Romans 15:13), in order to shew them the real department of his apostolic power, and that, however exercised, it would not attempt to rule their faith, but only to secure to them, by purifying them, joy in believing. He proceeds to say, that it was the probable disturbance of this joy, which induced bim to forego his visit.

---

### References

Alford, Henry. [*The Greek Testament.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mXQOAQAAIAAJ) Vol. 2. Boston: Lee, 1878.

Liddell, Henry George; Scott, Robert; et al. [*A Greek-English Lexicon.*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/search) 9th ed. Oxford: Clarendon, 1940.

Meyer, Heinrich August Wilhelm. [*Critical and Exegetical Handbook to the Epistles to the Corinthians.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9_s2AAAAMAAJ) Trans. Bannerman, David Douglas. Ed. Dickson, William P. New York: Funk, 1884.

Smyth, Herbert Weir. [*A Greek Grammar for Colleges.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TK9MAAAAMAAJ) New York: American Book, 1920.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> LSJ, p. 1013
<sup>2</sup> Smyth, Part 3, §[866](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0007%3Apart%3D3%3Achapter%3D23)
<sup>3</sup> LSJ, p. 1013
<sup>4</sup> LSJ, p. 446
<sup>5</sup> LSJ, p. 447
<sup>6</sup> LSJ, p. 309
<sup>7</sup> LSJ, p. 309
<sup>8</sup> p. [435](https://books.google.com/books?id=9_s2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA435#v=onepage&q&f=true)
<sup>9</sup> p. 1920
<sup>10</sup> cp. Col. 1:7, 4:7
<sup>11</sup> p. [635](https://books.google.com/books?id=mXQOAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA635#v=onepage&q&f=true)
<sup>12</sup> ‘fides enim prorsus ab hominum jugo soluta liberrimaque esse debet.’ ► “For faith should be absolutely unfettered and free from the yoke of men.”